# ical/ics: Better way to do a daily 3-month reminder every year

Tags: icalendar, rrule

I am trying to setup a daily 3-month reminder that would occur every year; that is a reminder that occurs daily starting August 1st and ending October 31st, every year.  I poured over the RFC and crafted a `RRULE` that I am sure will work, but I am curious: is there a better way?

`RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=8,9,10;BYMONTHDAY=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31`

This ICS is going to be imported into Google calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a simpler solution. Just create a rule to recur `DAILY` but only in months 8, 9 and 10:

```
FREQ=DAILY;BYMONTH=8,9,10
```

Your start date should be August 1st.
[See the results](http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/reaas?dtstart=20200801&rrule=FREQ%3DDAILY%3BBYMONTH%3D8%2C9%2C10&skip=&max_instances=1000&expansion_window_end=21000101T000000) as generated by [recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com](http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/).